# Why adding item into .NET CheckedListBox always throw error?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I'm not too familiar with **C#** programming for **winform**.
Below is my code

```
List<string> contacts = (List<string>)message;
Console.WriteLine(">>> REFRESH CONTACTS...");
for (int n = 0; n < contacts.Count; n++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Step 1");
    if (!listBox1.Items.Contains(contacts[n]))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Step 2");
        listBox1.Items.Insert(n, contacts[n]);
        Console.WriteLine("Step 3");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Step 4");
}
```

This code never passed **"Step 2"**, error message is:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll
```

WHY???

Comment: This message is generic. Go to Debug menu, choosing Exceptions... and checking off the Thrown option next to Common Language Runtime Exceptions. It'll help identify the error.

Comment: Can you please provide the code of how you create your `message`. The code you have posted itself worked for me.

Comment: is listbox1 bound to anything? Are you sure you don't make any cross threading calls?

Comment: Yes, after trying @Pv-Viana, I found that my message object was created by different thread. So the problem fixed thanks :)

Comment: @KuntoFullstack You're welcome sir. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
  List<string> contacts = new List<string>();
    contacts.Add("message");
    Console.WriteLine(">>> REFRESH CONTACTS...");

for (int n = 0; n < contacts.Count; n++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Step 1");
    if (!listBox1.Items.Contains(contacts[n]))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Step 2");
        listBox1.Items.Insert(n, contacts[n]);
        Console.WriteLine("Step 3");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Step 4");
}
```